# Row Level Action on Contact Related List on Account Record Page

Tags: related-list

I want to add an addition row-level action to what is currently appearing in the Contact Related List of Account record Detail Page. I am wondering if that is possible by configuration.

Screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Cab you let us know where do you want to add it and some details around it.

Comment: I want it in the Contact Related List of Account Record. I want to add an additional Row Level action, other than 'View Relationship' and 'Edit Relationship' as shown in screenshot in the post. I am looking forward to achieve it by some configurational approach. I checked options in Page Layout Editor but could not find anything.